# Write the Value of a variable in JS into HTML Div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display list of plugins that are not installed but required on c client's Browser.
The following code first takes a txt file(which contains the required plugins) as input. After that it compares to the list of plugins installed on the browser. What I get is just what is written in the div tag instead of plugin names which are not installed on the browser. 
The contents of the file test.txt are -- Flash
                                         Java
Please help!

```js
function LoadFile(e) {


    //Reading and displaying the Plugins Required
    var div = document.getElementById('txt');

    var oFrame = document.getElementById("frmFile");
    var strRawContents = oFrame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    while (strRawContents.indexOf("\r") >= 0)
        strRawContents = strRawContents.replace("\r", "");
    var arrLines = strRawContents.split("\n");
    document.writeln("File " + oFrame.src + " has " + arrLines.length + " line(s)<br/>");

    e.preventDefault();

    for (var i = 0; i < arrLines.length; i++) {
        var temp = false;
        var curLine = arrLines[i];
        document.write("<br/>Line #" + (i + 1) + " is: '" + curLine + "'<br/>");
        for (var j = 0; j < navigator.plugins.length; j++) {
            var plugin = navigator.plugins[j];
            var plugin_name = plugin.name;
            var n = plugin_name.search(curLine);
            if (n != -1) {
                document.write("Plugin Present<br/>");
                temp = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (temp == false) {
            document.write("Plugin is not present<br/>");
            div.innerHTML = plugin_name;

        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<iframe id="frmFile" src="test.txt" onload="LoadFile();" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src ="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="txt"> This is where it should input</div>
</head>
<body>
<table id="info" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="1px" style="empty-cells:show;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="background-color: #e0a0b0;" />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **"I dont get the desired output."** will get your question closed. please explain more specifically what is the **"desired output"** and what you get instead.

Comment: What should happen is that in the div it should display the plugins not present, instead it displays what i've written. The output should also display the list of plugins installed which is not!

Answer (score 2):

A few mistakes you made.

1. iframe needs to be in the `<body>` tag of the html.
2. `<div id="txt">` should be inside `<body>` tag as well.
3. to get the HTML source code of your iframe, it needs to be `window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML;`.
4. for the purpose of jsFiddle, `document.write()` is disabled. similarly, undefined `e` is disabled. Also jsFiddle does not allow cross site iframe, so a dummy page from its own site is used.

Corrected working example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fsj7hr1/10/)

Answer (score -1):

To change a value for an html-tag (assumig it allows it) would be, in your case for

```
<div id="txt"> This is where it should input</div>
```

Would in Javascript look like this:

```
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=yourValue;
```

Comment: I did try this but What i get is what I have written in the tag here "This is where it should input" instead of plugin names which are not present in test.txt"